# How to run a linux script before launching gdb debugging in Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, debugging, gdb

How do I give commands to run before starting gdb debugging in Eclipse ?

Actually I want to execute few scripts that set environment variables (export vars) and execute a bunch of other programs before gdb process is launched from eclipse to debug my program.

I tried doing the following in debugger tab option:

```
<command> && <path-to-gdb-executable>
```

But I got the error that eclipse cannot execute gdb as given in above statement.
Please help - I actually want to execute a script called "before-launch-commands.sh" before debugging is started by gdb. I am trying to execute a cpp program under eclipse kepler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Eclipse *Debug Configurations* can already setup environment variables for you. I'm going to assume that that isn't sufficient, or you'd have already done it.

The first thing to do is create a new script, `wrapped-gdb.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Export any variables we need.
# Note that '.' (dot) is like an "include" statement.
. /path/to/before-launch-commands.sh

# Run GDB using the parameters passed in
exec /path/to/gdb "$@"
```

Next, set that script executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/wrapped-gdb.sh
```

Finally, go to the `Debugger` tab in the debug configuration dialog, and in the box marked "GDB Debugger" enter `/path/to/wrapped-gdb.sh`.

When you launch your debug session it should now Do The Right Thing.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you said but got the following error now on debug launch - " Could not determine GDB version after sending /path/to/wrapped-gdb.sh  --version" and launch is terminated. So now how to delegate the arguments like --version etc to the gdb called in wrapped-gdb.sh ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932964/linux-how-do-i-delegate-exotic-commandline-arguments-using-a-script

i looked into this and ideally it should work i guess....

Comment: If you did it right then `wrapped-gdb.sh --version` should just work. What does it say when you run it manually?

Comment: Actually the debugger profile selected in eclipse was GDB DSF and now i changed it by creating a new process debug launcher and it worked for the first part and now it's screaming for .gdbinit not found. I am finding where it is and will copy it in my user's home. I think after this it should work. Any idea where is .gdbinit - it's not there in the folder where gdb executable is located.

Comment: .gdbinit is a file you can create yourself. It can contain any gdb commands you like.